# How to remove forward and backward slashes from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to remove all the forward and backward slash characters from the string using the Javascript.

Here is what I have tried:

```
var str = "//hcandna\\"
str.replace(/\\/g,'');
```

I also tried using `str.replace(/\\///g,'')`, but I am not able to do it.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just replace `\/` *or* (`|`) `\\` to remove all occurrences:

```js
var str = "//hcandna\\"
console.log( str.replace(/\\|\//g,'') );
```

Little side note about escaping in your RegEx:

A slash `\` in front of a reserved character, is to escape it from it's function and just represent it as a char. That's why your approach `\\//` did not make sense. You escapes `\` with `\`, so it becomes `\\`. But if you want to escape `/`, you need to do it like this too: `\/`.

Answer (score 3):

You want something more like this:

```js
var str = "//hcandna\\"
str=str.replace(/[\/\\]/g,'');
console.log(str);
```

This will search for the set of characters containing a forward or backward slash and replace them globally.  What you had requires a backslash followed by a forward slash.

Here's the output from Node:

```
  str.replace(/[\/\\]/g,'')
  'hcandna'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the result to a new string like:

```
var newstr = str.replace(/(\\|\/)+/ig, '');
```

Comment: Neither the `+` nor the `i` are required.  Case insensitive makes no sense when replacing slashes.  `+` isn't required since it has a `g` qualifier.

Comment: That depends on the size of the slash.. and it's working on all sizes.. Yeah, okay, I know, I triggered a cascading typo effect with belts and buckles, happens sometimes ;)

Comment: depends on the size of the slash?  What does that mean?

Comment: It was a joke, but clearly it wasn't a very good one, sorry about that. :)

Comment: No worries. :)  I thought it might be, but I also thought it might be something I didn't know. :)

Comment: And, to be complete, the brackets aren't required too, because you will never use this matching group. ;)

Comment: Oh, you mean the parantheses? Well, they add to readability and that's always a good thing, I think. Don't know what you mean about the last part, as it works just fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet

```
str.replace(/(\\|\/)/g,'');
```